# Which PPA to purge in resolving this 404 error in apt-get udpate?

Tags: apt, updates, package-management, ppa

`$ sudo apt-get update` is breaking and giving the following error:

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/joh/ppa/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages
```

I've tried looking at `/etc/apt/sources.list` but i can't find any `.../joh/ppa/...` to uncomment. My sources.list is pasted here: http://pastebin.com/UuzDhZCg

- Which package do i uncomment/purge to resolve the 404 error?
- How do i skip this package and continue the update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Run `sudo nautilus` on terminal to open nautilus with super user privileges.
- Go into `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory and find the `joh` PPA file(like `joh-PPA-saucy.list`) and then delete it.

Usually files related to PPA's are stored in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory.

OR

- Simply run this command to purge joh's PPA,

  ```
  sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:joh/ppa
  ```